# What is the Blue Debri that floats around?

Tags: pulsar-lost-colony

In Pulsar Lost Colony there is blue debris floating around in hard to reach places and when you destroy an enemy and it seems like you can collect them but most of the time you just ram into them. The picture below shows some that surrounded by mines so I feel like it SHOULD do something...

[image: The blue glowing debris]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are debris from ships or other objects like stations that have been partially or completely destroyed. When you get close to them they will sort of dissapear and end up in the cargo bay of your ship. Most will be scrap but sometimes you can find weapons and other cool stuff. You can either mount these things on your ship or sell them for credits at your next repair station.

Press ESC and then click "ship components" to view the items in your cargo bay.

Comment: It should also be noted that if your cargo is full the blue debri will not be picked up. That is where my confusion was.